# PagedList MVC 3 - Page Numbers not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PagedList.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PagedList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>ViewPage1</title>
    <link href="../../Public/css/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table class="tableEmptyStyle">
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>          
            <th>
                Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>            
        </tr>
        <%            
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.OnePageDivisions)
           { %>
        <tr>
           <td>
                <%: item.Code %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: item.Name %>
            </td>
         </tr>
        <% Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageDivisions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly); %>
        <% } %>        
    </table>
```

Then from the controller I am getting the list and

ViewBag.OnePageDivisions = allList

I am able to get the list and display it,

the problem is the page numbers below are not showing.

The CSS, "PagedList.css" was taken from the package. Any help is appreciated

I am using MVC 3, PagedList 1.15.0.0 and PagedList.Mvc 3.18.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<% Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageDivisions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly); %>
```

To

```
<%: Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageDivisions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly) %>
```